# Posting to Facebook wall with customize settings on Android using Facebook api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-wall

[Cardio Trainer Example Image Link](http://postimage.org/image/6otopxvnv/)

I'm trying to post on wall with some custom settings as Example image via "Cardio Trainer" android api. This is an automatically sharing process without facebook feed dialog. But I've three main problems.

1. I want my post not sharable as in example photo. I couldnt find any approach.
2. I couldn't embeded link in description part (in photo=>"Calorific diet tracker. Try it!").
3. On the top of the example image, the text will be ended "Cardio Trainer ile". But mine continue "shared a link"

Comment: i tried me/feed post. Now I know I sould use open graph share

Answer (score 0):

The image you posted is a story generated by an Open Graph share, and not a regular /me/feed post. If you want something similar, you will need to create some Open Graph actions and objects for your app.

Comment: Thank you u re right. But i still ve problems. The publish seems at profile page but doesnt seem at homepage in news feed. And i dont know hot paste url in description. Do u know how to do ? thank u